# Manifest file Generation

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am new to Visual Studio.I have developed a form application in Visual Studio which will be used in my organisation.
When I build this application as Setup.exe, one manifest file is created automatically.This XML file has reference of **"https://www.w3.org"**.
My Seniors told me that our client may raise the question about this web-site , which is third party web-site and hence we cannot use the application.

1. Is there any way to remove the reference of **"https://www.w3.org"**    completely ?
2. Can I give surety to my clients and seniors that using reference of this web-site will not create problem in future?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

The `www.w3.org` website is the official World Wide Web Consortium web-site, an international body that is the recognized holder of all official Web Standards. In fact, it is the body that *created and owns* the [XML standard](http://www.w3.org/XML/). Well-formed XML files are supposed to reference the master schema hosted on the `www.w3.org` website. The fact that it references that website rather than some other URL is what makes it standards conformant.

```
<xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

If your client is confused by that, send them to the [website](http://www.w3.org/Consortium/) to read about it. It would probably be good if your Seniors read up on it as well.